# Undelete a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The following question was posted yesterday on Ask Different:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365151/emacs-gui-no-longer-opens-from-the-terminal-after-a-brew-upgrade

I engaged with the OP to try help resolve their problem. After arriving at the solution, I was not able to post an answer as I was on my phone and away from computer. I planned to post an answer soon.

However, the OP deleted the question thinking that they were not getting the answer.

Can OP/users with necessary privilege vote to undelete it so that appropriate answer can be posted for the question?

**Update**: After the question was undeleted and an answer was posted, OP appears to have deleted the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've undeleted the question; even though it might not be useful for the author anymore, you might be able to help future visitors with a similar problem.

Note that as a 10k user, you can flag posts like these for ♦ moderator attention. That's probably quicker, and that way we keep Meta for questions about Ask Different where *everybody* can participate.

Comment: FWIW, posting a question on Meta is not *wrong*; moderators get notified about those as well.